# Surjective map of abelian groups properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Given a surjective map $f\colon M \to N $, where $M$ and $N$ are abelian groups, is it true that $M \cong \operatorname{Ker}(f) \oplus \operatorname{Im}(f)$? Since the map is surjective $\operatorname{Im}(f) \cong N $.

Comment: $f$ is surjective then $Im(f)=N$.

Comment: It is true whenever $N$ is a free abelian group.

Comment: Do you mean "surjective homomorphism" rather than "surjective map"?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x)=[x]_{\operatorname{mod} 2}$. Then $\operatorname{ker}(f)=2\mathbb{Z}$, but $\mathbb{Z}\not\cong 2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ because the right-hand group has non-zero elements of order $2$, while the left-hand group have not.

Answer (score 0):

No. For prime $p$, the group $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ cannot be split as the direct sum of proper subgroups, but admits a surjective homomorphism onto $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Another example is the [Prüfer $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$, which has plenty of endomorphisms all of which (except of course the zero map), are surjective, but it cannot be split as a direct sum of proper subgroups.